# How can I reference a file path stored on mongodb in a react component?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, multer

I have a mongodb document that has a property avatarImage an it looks like this:

```
{
    ...,
    "avatarImage": "uploads/584563-jean.jpg",
    ...
}
```

Then in App.js component I fetch this object and use the path stored in avatarImage as an image source like this:

```
<img src={`http://localhost:8080/${profileImage}`} />
```

`profileImage` is a state variable that its initialised with the avatarImage value.

But the image is not displayed at all. Uploads folder is in `root/uploads`

Comment: What are you using to serve these assets? Express? Or a simple http-server?

Comment: I am using express

Comment: Then you'll want to use this: `app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));` BEFORE the `app.listen(...)` call. This tells express to serve files within `uploads` for any `/uploads/file` GET requests.

Comment: That was amazing. I have been using this app.use(express.static("uploads")); without the  route. It works now. thank you.